# Gray weird layer after send and app to playstore

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was developing an app normally, the apk generated by android studio is everything ok. I started to have some problem when I sended my frist version to playstore google. I did to upload correctly but when the google take me to do the download from playstore, it come the problem. The login page is ok but when I acess the main page of the app, there is a grey layter over the drawer widget the contain the main menu of the of (I´ll send a print screen). Beside that, over the google map widget on the main page also there is the same grey shape like a layer. I need some help to solve them because I didt find any information on internet about this issue. This error have happend just after send the apk ou app bundle to playstore, in all test whit apk is everything ok.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtKqo.jpg)

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k17Og.jpg)
I took in this message 4 images. 2 whit de issue and 2 correct.enter image description here

Comment: You have to share code for other to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
DefaultTabController( // Added
length: 4, // Added
initialIndex: 0, //Added
child: Scaffold(
key: _scaffoldKey,
floatingActionButton:
this.pilotoTemVooAssumido=='1' ?
this.tabIndex==0 ?
FloatingActionButton(
backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
onPressed: () async {
},
child: Icon(Icons.delete_forever,color: Colors.white,),
) : null : null,
appBar: AppBar(
backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(37, 67, 154, 1),
//LARANJA Color.fromRGBO(249, 138, 18, 1) AZUL "Color.fromRGBO(37, 67, 154, 1)"
title: Text(
"Ata Brasil VA", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
),
drawer: buildDrawer(),
body: buildBody(tabIndex),
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(

selectedItemColor: Color.fromRGBO(249, 138, 18, 1),
unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
//backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(249, 138, 18, 1) ,
backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(37, 67, 154, 1),
currentIndex: tabIndex,
onTap: (int index) {
},
items: [
BottomNavigationBarItem(
icon: Icon(Icons.home),
title: Text('Home'),
),
BottomNavigationBarItem(
icon: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
title: Text('Últimos Voos'),
),
BottomNavigationBarItem(
icon: Icon(Icons.map),
title: Text('Ao Vivo'),
),
]),
));
```